# Identification of existance of Corda accounts in main controller API?

Tags: kotlin, corda

How to identify that whether the input string is an account name or host party name from a single parameter in an API function and then route query accordingly in Corda accounts?

Comment: how does the account name or host party name looks? what have you tried? share some code

Answer (score 1):

To check if the string name is a well-known counterparty you could use something like this

```
Party party = proxy.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(CordaX500Name.parse("O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"));
```

To check if an account exists with a particular input string name you could hit the vault using

```
Vault.Page<AccountInfo> accounts = proxy.vaultQuery(AccountInfo.class);
List<StateAndRef<AccountInfo>>  accountInfos = accounts.getStates();
```

and check if an account with the specified input name exists in accountInfos.

Comment: Thankyou Sneha :) I was actually trying to get the other way around. Is it feasible to use AccountInfoByName flow here?  

(https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/workflows/flows/AccountInfoByName.kt )